Does a zero tensor product mean commutator also zero?
I am studying zeroth law of thermodynamics of Black Holes and at some point I came across the following equation :
$$T^{a}_{b} \chi_{a} \chi^{b}=0$$
where $T$ is energy-momentum tensor and $\chi$ is killing vector. It then said, also
$$\chi_{[c}T_{a]b}\chi^{b}=0$$
Can someone explain if the first one holds then how does it implies the second?

This is essentially (Lorentizan) linear algebra and is summarized in a short paragraph in Wald (middle of page 334), relying on the dominant energy condition:

Lemma.
Let $(V,g)$ be an $(n+1)$ Lorentzian inner product space, and let $T$ be a  symmetric $(0,2)$ tensor on $V$ and $\chi\in V$ a given vector. If

$\chi$ is non-zero and null,
$T(\chi,\chi)=0$,
$T(\chi,\cdot)$ is a causal covector (i.e by definition we mean the metrically-related vector $T(\chi,\cdot)^{\sharp}$ is causal, i.e $g^{cb}\chi^aT_{ab}=\chi^aT_a^{\,c}$ is causal),

then $T(\chi,\cdot)$ and $\chi^{\flat}=g(\chi,\cdot)$ are linearly dependent, or equivalently, their wedge product is zero, i.e in terms of indices, $\chi_{[c}T_{a]b}\chi^b=0$.

In the context of black hole mechanics (e.g as in Wald), we’re studying a Killing horizon, i.e we study what happens if we have a non-trivial spacetime Killing field $\chi$ which is normal to a null hypersurface. Also, for physical reasons we suppose $T$ satisfies say the dominant-energy condition. So, in this setting, the first and third bullet points are satisfied on the horizon; the middle bullet point can also be proved (see Wald) but is also what you’re taking as your starting point, so I won’t pursue this point further.
The proof of the lemma is now a simple causality argument.

The second bullet point can be written as $g(T(\chi,\cdot)^{\sharp},\chi)=T(\chi,\chi)=0$, i.e the vector $T(\chi,\cdot)^{\sharp}$ is orthogonal to $\chi$.
Since $\chi$ is a non-zero null vector, its orthogonal complement does not contain any timelike vectors (because the orthogonal complement of timelike vectors consists of spacelike vectors only). In particular, by point (1), the vector $T(\chi,\cdot)^{\sharp}$ cannot be timelike; by the third bullet point, it follows that $T(\chi,\cdot)^{\sharp}$ is a null vector.
Combining points (1) and (2), we see that $T(\chi,\cdot)^{\sharp}$ is a null vector which is orthogonal to the non-zero null vector $\chi$. This implies $T(\chi,\cdot)^{\sharp}$ is a multiple of $\chi$… again this is a standard fact about null vectors. Equivalently, the covector $T(\chi,\cdot)$ is proportional to $\chi^{\flat}=g(\chi,\cdot)$, hence their wedge product vanishes.


wald at page#334 just said "$\chi_{[c}T_{a]b}\chi^{b}=0$". He didn't prove it! where this lemma given in the book ?

@TalhaAhmed Wald proves $T(\chi,\chi)=0$ i.e $T_{ab}\chi^a\chi^b=0$ by referring to an equation in a previous page (eq 12.5.22 on page 334). This is not explicitly stated as a lemma in Wald. I’m just isolating the key part of the argument which Wald very concisely expresses in the middle of page 334.

I will take advantage of the abstract index notation.
I assume that the Killing horizon is made of integral lines of the Killing vector $\chi$. Exactly  on the horizon $\chi$ becomes light like.
It does not seem to me that the former identity alone implies the latter automatically.
Consider a local coordinate system $u,v,\Omega$ adapted to the horizon so that both $$\chi^a \equiv  \partial_u, \quad \chi_a \equiv dv$$ and $\Omega$ is a set of transverse coordinates, typically two angles.
The two identities above means
$$\chi^a = \delta^a_u, \quad \chi_a =\delta_a^v.$$
Therefore, the first equation you wrote just says that
$$T_{uu}=0.$$
The second one, in view of the only non vanishing components of $\chi^a$ boils down to
$$\chi_a T_{bu}- \chi_b T_{au}=0.$$
Since the only non vanishing component of $\chi_a$ is $\chi_v$, the only relevant case is, up to an overall sign,
$$\chi_v T_{bu}- \chi_b T_{vu}=0.$$
Here, the only cases to be considered are $b=u$ and $b=\Omega$. In the first case the identity is automatically true because $\chi_a$ does not have $u$ component and $T_{uu}=0$. I cannot say anything about the other case.
The wanted identity (your second one), given your first identity, is true if and only if $$T_{u\Omega}(=T_{\Omega u})=0.$$
Maybe the fact is true for some reason. I had to do with these things many years ago, I do not remember, sorry.
Addendum. As you see from peek-a-boo’s answer, the added hypothesis to be used is the requirement that $T_{ab}\chi^b$ is causal. This permits to conclude that this covector is parallel to $\chi_a$ (since it is orthogonal to the light like convector $\chi_a$) and thus the components $T_{\Omega u}$ must vanish.
